# Laravel Eloquent with `has` and `where` on dates

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I try to get records on relation when there is only one record in the one to many relation and only the records where the `start_date` is bigger than now() and here is what I'm trying:

```
$newStarters = User::has('periods', 1)->with(['periods' => function($q) {
            $q->where('start_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek(2)->format('Y-m-d') );
        }])->get();
```

in this case the date filter does not applies.

What is the propper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking this:

```
$newStarters = User::whereHas('periods',  function($q) {
            $q->where('start_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subWeek(2)->format('Y-m-d') );
        }, '=', 1)->get();
```

See [Query relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) section for more details.

Comment: But in this case would not take in consideration that only one record should exits in the relation. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You can use has and whereHas together to get what you need.

Comment: @fefe I've updated. If you want to get when there is exact one record, you can pass additional operator and count as in my updated answer

Comment: thanks @Marcin Nabiałek I just tried out but like that I have all the non filtered records